# Наследование - обязательно ли переопределять все виртуальные функции?

Tags: c++, наследование, виртуальная-функция

Есть базовый абстрактный класс:

```
class Duck{
protected:
    FlyBehavior *flyBehavior;
    QuackBehavior *quackBehavior;
public:
    Duck () {}
    virtual void display() = 0;
    virtual void performFly() = 0;
    virtual void performQuack() = 0;
    virtual void swim() = 0;
};
```

Есть класс-наследник:

```
class MallardDuck : public Duck
{
public:
    MallardDuck(){
        quackBehavior = new Quack();
        flyBehavior = new FlyWithWings();
    }

    void display() {
        std::cout << "I'm a real Mallard duck" << std::endl;
    }
    void performFly() {
        Duck::performFly();
    }
    void performQuack() {
        Duck::performQuack();
    }
    void swim() {
        Duck::swim();
    }
};
```

Вопрос в следующем: как сделать так, чтобы функции не приходилось переопределять в дочернем классе, но при этом сохранилось родительское поведение в случае, если функция не переопределена?
Т.е. мне нужно, чтобы было возможно, не трогая родительский класс, переопределить функцию в дочернем, а до тех пор, пока функция не переопределена, выполнялась родительская. Или добавить в родительскую функцию, которая выполнялась бы во всех дочерних без изменений в них. Это возможно?

Comment: А что будет выполняться родительского? Вот тут, например: `Duck::performFly();` - что тут будет выполняться, если там ничего нет?... Если вы говорите именно про абстрактный класс?...

Comment: @Harry Идея в том, чтобы убрать такие переопределения, как `Duck::performFly()`. Т.е. при добавлении в родительский класс функции она автоматически будет доступна в дочерних классах, без подобных костылей. Функции базового класса определены ниже, я не стала их приводить.

Comment: Так в чем проблема. Ответ: да, можно. И для этого не надо никаких ухищрений предпринимать. Покажите пример кода, как Вы хотите это использовать, а то у Вас действительно чисто абстрактный родитель и для потомков его обязательно переопределять все абстрактные методы. Если же методы будут не абстрактными, но виртуальными их переопределять не надо.

Comment: Вы хотите [это](https://ideone.com/bsoMpY)?

Comment: Тогда ничего не понимаю. Функции базового и так доступны в производном...

Comment: @RomanOzhegov, спасибо, поняла. Сделать не чисто абстрактными, а просто виртуальными. А то я запуталась слегка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если методы будут не абстрактными, но виртуальными их переопределять не надо.